# can anybody explain the output of the following Java code?

Tags: java, polymorphism

```
class A{
    int i = 1;
    A(){play();}
    void play(){System.out.print(i);}
}
class B extends A{ 
    int i = 2;
    B(){play();}
    void play(){System.out.print(i);}
} 
public class Test extends B{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        new Test();
    }
}
```

output:
02

can anybody explain the output of the above Java code?Thx.

Comment: Add a `System.out.print('...')` statement on each constructor/method (with a descriptive message) and you will see the order in which they're invoked, and other details that should help you here.

Comment: This is because the fact that Parent will initialize first then followed by Child.

Flow:

    A <-- B <--Test

But Why printed `0 2` instead of `1 2` ?

This is because of **method overriding** done for `play()`, where on first invoking play() from A's constructor B's Play() will be called and variable i of B is not initialized and default value 0 is printed.

Answer (score 0):

Because Test class doesn't constructor and it extends from B class. Therefore, it will call B constructor and output is 2.

Comment: Output is `02` not `2`

Comment: @VishalSantharam can you help provide me some reading materials of polymorphism in Java.I'm reading <Thinking in Java> recently,but it doesn't make me clear about polymorphism .I don't understand why polymorphism  mechanism still works when firstly call paly() in class A of this example.(Thank you)